# how to fetch name attribute for jquery context menu plugin

Tags: jquery

How to fetch the name attribute for jquery context menu plugin. i am able to get key in call back but not able to get name. My code is given below.
Here in my code, the values of "possibleStatuesArray" will come as submenue under "Change circuit status".

```
possibleStatuesArray=['RFS','IS','OOS'];

function RightClickMenus(selectorName, possibleStatuesArray) {

    $.contextMenu({
        selector: selectorName, 
        items: {
                "fold1": {
                "name": "Change circuit status", 
                "items": {
                    "fold1-key1": {"name": possibleStatuesArray[0]},
                    "fold1-key2": {"name": possibleStatuesArray[1]},
                    "fold1-key3": {"name": possibleStatuesArray[2]}
                }
            },

        },
        callback: function(key, options) {
            alert("options**: " + options.key.name);
            // Do stuff when something gets clicked on
            console.log("options::::: " + options);
        },
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

http://jsfiddle.net/hgxc67Lm/3/

```
callback: function (key, options) {
    var name=$('.context-menu-list .hover:last').text();
    alert(name);
},
```

Comment: It is not working in my case as values of possibleStatuesArray is comming as submenu under "Change circuit status".